# Full Oracle 10g XE Database Can't Be Exported?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

The simple version of this question is: Is it possible to export all the data from an Oracle 10g XE database that has reached it's 4GB maximum size limit?

Now, here's the background:
My (Windows) Oracle 10g XE database has reached its maximum allowed database size of 4GB.  The solution I intended to implement to this problem was to upgrade to Oracle 11g XE which has a larger maximum size limit, and better reflects our production environment anyway.  Of course, in typical Oracle fashion, they do not have an upgrade-in-place option (at least not that I could find for XE).  So I decided to follow the instructions in the "Importing and Exporting Data between 10.2 XE and 11.2 XE" section of the Oracle 11g XE Installation Guide.  After fighting with SQLPlus for a while, I eventually reached step 3d of the instructions which instructs the user to enter the following (it doesn't specify the command-line rather than SQLPlus, but it means the command-line):

```
expdp system/system_password full=Y EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'APEX_%\'\",SCHEMA:\"LIKE \'FLOWS_%\'\" directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

That command results in the following output:

```
Export: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thursday, 29 September, 2011 10:19:11


Copyright (c) 2003, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "SYSTEM.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_06"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 863
ORA-12952: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 4 GB
```

I have deleted quite a bit of data from the USERS tablespace, but am unable to resize it because of the physical locations of the data.  And no matter what I do, I always get that same output.  I have tried running "Compact Storage" from the admin web application with no effect.

So my question is, am I missing something?  Or is Oracle really so incompetent as to leave people completely out of luck if their XE databases fill up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get to the point you need to export data, sounds like you just need some help coalescing the data so you can reduce the USERS tablespace size and increase the SYSTEM tablespace size to get past your issue.

You mentioned that you removed data from the USERS tablespace but can't resize. Since you can't reduce the tablespace size smaller than the highest block, reorganiza your table data by executing the following command for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MOVE <tablespace_name>;
```

The tablespace name can be the same tablespace that the table currently lives in, it will still reorganize the data and coalesce the data.

This statement will give you the text for this command for all the tables that live in USERS tablespace:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||' MOVE '||TABLESPACE_NAME||';' From dba_tables where tablespace_name='USERS';
```

Indexes will also have to be rebuilt (ALTER INDEX  REBUILD;) as the MOVE command invalidates them because it changes physical organization of the table data (blocks) instead of relocating row by row.

After the data is coalesced you can resize the USERS tablespace to reflect the data size.

Is it a pain? Yes. Is Oracle user friendly? They would love you to think so but its really not, especially when you hit some weird corner case that keeps you from doing the types of things you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you need some free space in the SYSTEM tablespace in order to export, and Oracle XE refuses to allocate it because the sum of SYSTEM+USERS has reached 4 Gb.

I would try to install an Oracle 10gR2 Standard Edition instance on a similar architecture, then shutdown Oracle XE and make a copy your existing USERS data file. Using "ALTER TABLESPACE" commands on the standard edition, you should be able to link the USERS tablespace to your existing data file, then export the data.

Comment: So I would have to install a whole new instance of Oracle 10g Standard Edition (for which I don't have a license) just so I can upgrade my XE instance from 10g to 11g without losing my data?  Seriously?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, because your 10g XE is currently full. Maybe you can perform some similar operation using 11g XE but I don't recommend it, you should use the same Oracle version with the same architecture to avoid compatibility issues.

Comment: Note that it seems the 11g XE has no limitation on the SYSTEM tablespace, so this problem should not occur anymore: "The resource limitations are the same as for Release 10.2, except that you can now store up to 11 GB of user data (**not including Express Edition system data**), as opposed to 4 GB in Release 10.2." http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#BJFEIJGJ

Comment: Wow...I think it would be a more effective use of my time to just sacrifice the data and rebuild what I can after I install 11g.  It seems like every time I think my opinion of Oracle has hit rock-bottom, something happens to lower it further.

Comment: I agree, we often face this problem when using 10g XE databases, this is really annoying!

Comment: Copy data files? Transportable Tablespaces is not supported in XE. You might be able to mount the database (datafiles+redo logs+ config files) to 10g Standard or Enterprise Edition binaries... that seems to be the method described in Oracle's docs... http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/server.102/b32391/upgrade.htm#CHDHIJGE ... but doing a major version upgrade (10gXE -> 11gXE) I suggest Export and then Import.